# Restore Windows XP Tablet Edition on Acer TravelMate c110

Tags: windows-xp, tablet

I'm asked to see what I can do about Acer TraveMate c110 with pen that refused to work.
Investigation showed that someone "smart" did something with Windows -- system information shows Windows XP Professional instead of XP Tablet Edition. Furthermore the Acer eRecovery doesn't work.
I fired up Acronis Disk Directory Suite and examined partitions. To my rejoice the hidden files needed for Acer eRecovery to work are still there. I suppose type of partition is wrong.

But big problem is that I don't have any Recovery CDs, since they are missing.
Any idea how to make Acer eRecovery work again?

Answer (score 2):

For using the system recovery check if **Acer Empowering Technology** is installed which contains a program called [Acer eRecovery Management](http://support.acer-euro.com/empowering_technology/utility2.html).

[image]

If not you can download it from the Acer website.

This program will let you restore your latest backup, but also to factory default (right after the initial install) or you can write one of those backups to a disk.

Check [this manual](ftp://ftp.support.acer-euro.com/notebook/empowering_technology/NB%20ET2%20user%27s%20guide/Acer%20eRecovery%20Management%20English.pdf) for more explanation on the tool or this [ftp site (Acer)](ftp://ftp.support.acer-euro.com/notebook/empowering_technology/utility/as_5510_9500/) for utilities if you can't find anything newer.

Comment: Unfortunately c110 is not supported by eRecovery technology.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting the recovery disk.